# Parsing an ExpandoObject into a typed class using reflection

Tags: c#, parsing

I've spent some time writing a library to parse JSON into a statically typed object.  Am I following most of the standard coding guidelines?  Any thoughts on what I could do better, or any edge cases that are missing and aren't taken care of?

```
private static T ParseDynamic(ExpandoObject input)
{
    //Parse when given an ExpandoObject
    T output = default(T);
    var dict = input as IDictionary<string, object>;
    ParseDictionary<T>(dict, out output);
    return output;
}
protected static void ParseDictionary(IDictionary<string, object> Dict, out object Target, Type explicitType)
{
    if(Dict == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Dictionary was null, cannot parse a null dictionary");
    }
    if (explicitType.IsArray)
    {
        var length = Dict.Keys.Count();
        Target = (Array)Activator.CreateInstance(explicitType, new object[] { length });
    }
    else
    {
        Target = Activator.CreateInstance(explicitType);
    }
    foreach (var property in Target.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        var propertyName = property.Name;
        if (Dict.ContainsKey(propertyName) && Dict[propertyName] != null)
        {
            var val = Dict[propertyName];
            var propertyVal = explicitType.GetProperty(propertyName);
            var expectedType = property.PropertyType;
            var valType = val.GetType();
            if(valType == expectedType)
            {
                //Hurray, we matched!
                propertyVal.SetValue(Target, val);
            }
            else if (valType != expectedType && val is IConvertible)
            {
                Type safeType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(expectedType) ?? expectedType;
                //Special Case - INT64 to DATETIME Conversion (UNIX Time)
                if((valType == typeof(long) || valType == typeof(long?))
                    && (safeType == typeof(DateTime) || safeType == typeof(DateTime?)))
                {
                    var longValue = (long)Convert.ChangeType(val, typeof(long));
                    var dateValue = UNIX_EPOCH.AddSeconds(longValue);
                    val = dateValue;
                }
                //Convert if possible
                var explicitVal = (val == null ? null : Convert.ChangeType(val, safeType));
                propertyVal.SetValue(Target, explicitVal, null);

            }
            else if (val is IDictionary<string, object>)
            {
                //Parse non-simple object
                var propType = propertyVal.PropertyType;
                object explicitVal = Activator.CreateInstance(propType);
                ParseDictionary(val as IDictionary<string, object>, out explicitVal, propType);
                propertyVal.SetValue(Target, explicitVal);
            }
            else if (val is IList)
            {
                //Parse list/enumeration/array
                Type elementType;
                if (expectedType.IsArray)
                {
                    //Array type is explicitly included with GetElementType
                    elementType = expectedType.GetElementType();
                }
                else if (expectedType.IsGenericType)
                {
                    //Get List type by inspecting generic argument
                    elementType = expectedType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    //Not sure how we'd get here if we're neither an array nor generic, but we can't really do much
                    continue;
                }
                //Create the necessary List implementation that we need
                var listType = typeof(List<>);
                var typedList = listType.MakeGenericType(elementType);
                var explicitList = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(typedList);
                foreach(var element in val as IList<object>)
                {
                    object explicitElement;
                    ParseDictionary(element as IDictionary<string, object>, out explicitElement, elementType);
                    explicitList.Add(explicitElement);
                }
                if(property.PropertyType.IsArray)
                {
                    //Convert from list to array if necessary
                    var arrayType = elementType.MakeArrayType();
                    var array = (Array)Activator.CreateInstance(arrayType, new object[] { explicitList.Count });
                    explicitList.CopyTo(array, 0);
                    propertyVal.SetValue(Target, array);
                }
                else
                {
                    propertyVal.SetValue(Target, explicitList);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Attempt to set it - will error if not compatible and all other checks are bypassed
                propertyVal.SetValue(Target, val);
            }
        }
    }
}    
protected static void ParseDictionary<K>(IDictionary<string, object> Dict, out K Target) where K : class, new()
{
    Target = new K();
    var explicitType = Target.GetType();
    var outObject = new object();
    ParseDictionary(Dict, out outObject, explicitType);
    Target = outObject as K;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some helpful answers.

Comment: Thanks!  Looking at it on my own, I just now realized that I've mixed my naming styles.

Comment: @akw5013 feel free to write a self answer pointing it out. We encourage self review.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`protected static void ParseDictionary(IDictionary<string, object> Dict, out object Target, Type explicitType)`

I would say this method declaration is a **big code smell**. Having a `void` method with an `out` parameter just isn't right.

Why don't you let the method return an `object` ? There is just no reason.

Although it had been already mentioned by [@akw5013](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/86136/akw5013) in his [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/106676/29371), based on the [NET naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) methodparameters should be named using `camelCase` casing.
If you choose a style for yourself, which is a valid decision, you should stick to this style. At this declaration you are mixing styles which is always a bad idea.

---

> ```
> if (Dict.ContainsKey(propertyName) && Dict[propertyName] != null)
> {
>     var val = Dict[propertyName];
>     var propertyVal = explicitType.GetProperty(propertyName);
> ```

This will be "incredible" slow. Internally this calls 3 times the `FindEntry(key)` method through the following methods

```
public bool ContainsKey(TKey key) {
    return FindEntry(key) >= 0;
}  

public TValue this[TKey key] {
    get {
        int i = FindEntry(key);
        if (i >= 0) return entries[i].value;
        ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException();
        return default(TValue);
    }
    set {
        Insert(key, value, false);
    }
}
```

if you would use `Dictionary.TryGetValue()` this would result in only one call to

```
public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value) {
    int i = FindEntry(key);
    if (i >= 0) {
        value = entries[i].value;
        return true;
    }
    value = default(TValue);
    return false;
}
```

but fortunately this problem is easy to fix like so

```
    object val;
    var propertyName = property.Name;
    if (Dict.TryGetValue(propertyName, out val) && val != null)
    {
        var propertyVal = explicitType.GetProperty(propertyName);
```

that had been easy, hadn't it ?

> ```
> if(valType == expectedType)
> {
>     //Hurray, we matched!
>     propertyVal.SetValue(Target, val);
> }
> else if (valType != expectedType && val is IConvertible)
> ```

if the execution comes to the `else if` there is a **100% chance** that `valType != expectedType` will be `true`.

> ```
> else if (valType != expectedType && val is IConvertible)
> {
>     Type safeType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(expectedType) ?? expectedType;
>     //Special Case - INT64 to DATETIME Conversion (UNIX Time)
>     if ((valType == typeof(long) || valType == typeof(long?))
>         && (safeType == typeof(DateTime) || safeType == typeof(DateTime?)))
>     {
>         var longValue = (long)Convert.ChangeType(val, typeof(long));
>         var dateValue = UNIX_EPOCH.AddSeconds(longValue);
>         val = dateValue;
>     }
>     //Convert if possible
>     var explicitVal = (val == null ? null : Convert.ChangeType(val, safeType));
>     propertyVal.SetValue(Target, explicitVal, null);
>
> }
> ```

the use of `dateValue` can just be skipped. Assigning the return value of `UNIX_EPOCH.AddSeconds()` to `val` is enough.

The tenary expression would IMO be better just an `if..else` like so

```
if (val == null)
{
    propertyVal.SetValue(Target, null, null);
}
else 
{
    propertyVal.SetValue(Target, Convert.ChangeType(val, safeType), null);
}
```

> ```
> else if (val is IDictionary<string, object>)
> {
>     //Parse non-simple object
>     var propType = propertyVal.PropertyType;
>     object explicitVal = Activator.CreateInstance(propType);
>     ParseDictionary(val as IDictionary<string, object>, out explicitVal, propType);
>     propertyVal.SetValue(Target, explicitVal);
> }
> ```

Here you are creating an instance of `propType` which is overwritten inside the recursively called `ParseDictionary()` method. Just skip it.

> ```
> var listType = typeof(List<>);
> var typedList = listType.MakeGenericType(elementType);
> ```

the `var listType` is only used once at the next line of code. You can compact this like so

```
var typedList = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(elementType);
```

and if you want you can just keep your pattern of `typeType` so `typedList` will become `listType`.

The creation of the `List` of this `else if` branch should be extracted to a separate method like so

```
private static IList ParseAsList(object val, Type expectedType, PropertyInfo property)
{
    Type elementType = null;
    if (expectedType.IsArray) //Array type is explicitly included with GetElementType
    {
        elementType = expectedType.GetElementType();
    }
    else if (expectedType.IsGenericType) //Get List type by inspecting generic argument
    {
        elementType = expectedType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    }

    var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(elementType);
    var explicitList = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(listType);

    foreach (var element in val as IList<object>)
    {
        object explicitElement = ParseDictionary(element as IDictionary<string, object>, elementType);
        explicitList.Add(explicitElement);
    }

    return explicitList;
}
```

which results in the branch beeing

```
else if (val is IList)
{
    //Parse list/enumeration/array

    if (!(expectedType.IsArray || expectedType.IsGenericType)
    {
        //Not sure how we'd get here if we're neither an array nor generic, but we can't really do much
        continue;
    }

    //Create the necessary List implementation that we need
    var explicitList = ParseAsList(val, expectedType, property);

    if (expectedType.IsArray)
    {
        //Convert from list to array if necessary
        var arrayType = expectedType.GetElementType().MakeArrayType();
        var array = (Array)Activator.CreateInstance(arrayType, new object[] { explicitList.Count });
        explicitList.CopyTo(array, 0);
        propertyVal.SetValue(Target, array);
    }
    else
    {
        propertyVal.SetValue(Target, explicitList);
    }
}
```

I couldn't come up with a better name than `ParseAsList()` so its just that.

The former `ParseDictionary()` method will now look like so

```
protected static object ParseDictionary(IDictionary<string, object> dict, Type explicitType)
{

    if (dict == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("dict", "Dictionary was null, cannot parse a null dictionary");
    }

    object target;

    if (explicitType.IsArray)
    {
        var length = dict.Keys.Count();
        target = (Array)Activator.CreateInstance(explicitType, new object[] { length });
    }
    else
    {
        target = Activator.CreateInstance(explicitType);
    }

    foreach (var property in target.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        var propertyName = property.Name;
        object val;

        if (dict.TryGetValue(propertyName, out val) && val != null)
        {
            var propertyVal = explicitType.GetProperty(propertyName);
            var expectedType = property.PropertyType;
            var valType = val.GetType();

            if (valType == expectedType)
            {
                propertyVal.SetValue(target, val);
            }
            else if (val is IConvertible)
            {
                Type safeType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(expectedType) ?? expectedType;

                //Special Case - INT64 to DATETIME Conversion (UNIX Time)
                if ((valType == typeof(long) || valType == typeof(long?))
                    && (safeType == typeof(DateTime) || safeType == typeof(DateTime?)))
                {
                    var longValue = (long)Convert.ChangeType(val, typeof(long));
                    val = UNIX_EPOCH.AddSeconds(longValue);
                }

                if (val == null)
                {
                    propertyVal.SetValue(target, null, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    propertyVal.SetValue(target, Convert.ChangeType(val, safeType), null);
                }
            }
            else if (val is IDictionary<string, object>)
            {
                //Parse non-simple object
                var propType = propertyVal.PropertyType;
                object explicitVal = ParseDictionary(val as IDictionary<string, object>, propType);

                propertyVal.SetValue(target, explicitVal);
            }
            else if (val is IList)
            {
                //Parse list/enumeration/array

                if (!(expectedType.IsArray || expectedType.IsGenericType))
                {
                    //Not sure how we'd get here if we're neither an array nor generic, but we can't really do much
                    continue;
                }

                //Create the necessary List implementation that we need
                var explicitList = ParseAsList(val, expectedType, property);

                if (expectedType.IsArray)
                {
                    //Convert from list to array if necessary
                    var arrayType = expectedType.GetElementType().MakeArrayType();
                    var array = (Array)Activator.CreateInstance(arrayType, new object[] { explicitList.Count });
                    explicitList.CopyTo(array, 0);
                    propertyVal.SetValue(target, array);
                }
                else
                {
                    propertyVal.SetValue(target, explicitList);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Attempt to set it - will error if not compatible and all other checks are bypassed
                propertyVal.SetValue(target, val);
            }
        }
    }
    return target;
}
```

As you can see I have added some vertical space (new lines) to structure the code a little bit better which makes it more readable too.

Comment: And I wasn't disappointed. Always a pleasure reading your answers. ++

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback!  The main reason I am stuffing values into variables when they are overridden/used once is just for easier debugging while I step through.  That way I can hover over the variable and get the value without having to add a watch to it.

Answer (score 3):

> `ParseDictionary(IDictionary<string, object> Dict, out object Target, Type explicitType)`

You should properly case the parameter names using camel casing.

`ParseDictionary(IDictionary<string, object> inputDictionary, out object targetObject, Type explicitType)`

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> if(Dict == null)
> {
>     throw new InvalidOperationException("Dictionary was null, cannot parse a null dictionary");
> }
> ```

Yes! I'm a *huge* fan of this kind of defensive coding. Plus you gave a meaningful message! Awesome! There is a problem though, you should use an `ArgumentNullException` and pass it the parameter that failed to muster. It's more semantically correct and provides even more information back to the developer. I encourage you to look up the documentation on the two different exceptions to see more about when each is appropriate.

---

> ```
>             else
>             {
>                 //Not sure how we'd get here if we're neither an array nor generic, but we can't really do much
>                 continue;
>             }
> ```

Well, if you don't think you could ever get there, maybe you should throw an exception? If you don't think an exception is necessary, or don't want to throw one in production, then consider using `Debug.Assert(false)` to ensure that you're aware of it if you ever do end up in this logic branch.

Comment: I knew there was an exception type that I was missing.  Thanks!

Comment: @akw5013 ^ Heslacher is right.